# OpenMP Thread Creation

Tags: c++, linux, parallel-processing, openmp, gnu-parallel

In the code below, will the OpenMP runtime re-create threads or does it reuse threads previously created - i.e., use a pool of threads?

Some colleagues argued that it would re-create the threads because the "#parallel" clause is nested inside the for; I doubted that and did some tests on GDB which shows that this is not the fact. Threads are actually reused.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void fun1() {
    for (int j=1; j<=5; j++) {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            printf("Hahaha %d -> %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
        }
    }
}

void fun2() {
    for (int j=1; j<=5; j++) {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
            printf("Hahaha %d -> %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    fun1();

    sleep(1);

    fun2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would assume it would reuse the same threads as it has not lost scope until it exits out of the outer most `for`. If it has not lost scope then I would assume there would be no join and if there is no join then it would continue to use the same threads.

Comment: What I am observing is that threads are reused even across different function calls - i.e., across the call to fun1 and fun2.

Comment: from what I can tell it has to do with OMP setting thread teams which I would assume is re-using that team throughout the life time of the project. which would cause the same threads to be used

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10596598/7968757) to a related although more runtime optimizing orientated question. There it is stated "Most OpenMP implementations create a number of threads on program startup and keep them for the duration of the program." (Sadly without any source for confirmation.) How do you observe that threads are reused?

Comment: @Shadow he uses `omp_get_thread_num()` does guarantee that they are re-used

Comment: @Shadow my apologies... that was a typo. it should say "does not"

Comment: "Most openmp implementations" keep a thread pool alive for an adjustable interval after exiting a parallel region so as to optimize the frequent case where a similar thread pool will be required.  Typically default timeout is 0.20 sec

Comment: To check if threads are re-created I use GDB, which can tell when a thread is created and when it finishes execution.

Comment: @JohnTortugo Oh, you already wrote that in your question. I must have read over it. I am so sorry.

Comment: If you already confirmed that thereads are pooled  by observing with gdb, then I don't understand why you ask the question. Maybe your question is *"Is it reasonable to assume that OpenMP implementations are thread-pooled?"* or *"Is my reasoning based on the following gdb output (included in the question) correct?"* Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenMP standard describes the semantics required of an implementation, not how those are achieved, therefore the standard says nothing about the use of thread pools.

However

1. The standard does have rules about the persistence of thread-local storage which mean that a thread pool is the easiest way to achieve the required semantics.
2. The people who write OpenMP implementations are not idiots, so use implementations which are as fast as possible (and, therefore, use thread pools).

Therefore while you cannot guarantee that a thread pool is used you can reasonably expect that it is.

As to validation of this statement, look at the code for open-source OpenMP runtimes such as [LLVM](http://openmp.llvm.org) (which is also the runtime used by Intel compilers), and GCC's [gomp](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp/).

p.s. The use of thread pools has nothing to do with use of any specific OpenMP interfaces, though, of course, if you force an increase in the number of threads, new threads will have to be created in addition to those already in existence.